# Generate update changes as delta scripts

Tags: java, spring, h2, flyway

I work with H2/J2EE/Spring application, and use Flyway to update production database on a production server - all is fine. The problem is that it is always very complicated to merge developer H2 changes with production H2 (i.e generate flyway delta script). How is it possible in any way to trace all db changes in consequent historical way to generate these SQL changes? (All DB updates are done with admin frontend)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [trace option](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#trace_options) and then create a SQL script from the trace file using the [ConvertTraceFile](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/ConvertTraceFile.html) tool.

Comment: Great! But - what about automation of this invocation?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the information in trace file is not really what i need, especially it logs all selects, and all what is happening during session (accessing model data)... What i need is to achieve all schema changes (ALTER, CREATE, etc) and data modifications (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). But thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 0):

So nobody will share you knowledge - how to easily collect changes in database data and schema for me? :) Cause my temporary solution was to checkout h2 (my version) from their SVN, and modify org.h2.message.TraceSystem java class in the following manner:

```
public void write(int level, String module, String s, Throwable t) {
    ...


            String s2 = s.toUpperCase();
            if (s2.indexOf("SELECT") != -1) {
                return; // :)
            }

            writeFile(format2(s2), t);

}
```

Now i am at least able to grab the changes :) (with ConvertTraceFile for .trace.db )